# Ubuntu 20.04 + DisplayLink three screens

Tags: multiple-monitors, displaylink

I have a Dell XPS 13 9310 laptop that's connected to Dell WD19B docking station.
I Have three screens connected to the dock + the laptops screen, and for some reason all screens are detected and Ubuntu acts as if all monitors are working but one of the screens always shows "No Signal".

is there any way I can get four screens working or is this an issue with DisplayLink?

this is xrandr output, which also seems to indicate all monitors are working

```
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 7680 x 1200, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected 1920x1200+0+0 (0x28) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 290mm x 180mm
    Identifier: 0x21
    Timestamp:  767795
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 0.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
  1920x1200 (0x28) 193.250MHz -HSync +VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1920 start 2056 end 2256 total 2592 skew    0 clock  74.56KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1203 end 1209 total 1245           clock  59.88Hz
XWAYLAND8 connected 1920x1080+3840+0 (0x29) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
    Identifier: 0x551
    Timestamp:  767795
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 0.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       1
    CRTCs:      1
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
  1920x1080 (0x29) 173.000MHz -HSync +VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1920 start 2048 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock  67.16KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1120           clock  59.96Hz
XWAYLAND9 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (0x29) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
    Identifier: 0x553
    Timestamp:  767795
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 0.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       2
    CRTCs:      2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
  1920x1080 (0x29) 173.000MHz -HSync +VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1920 start 2048 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock  67.16KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1120           clock  59.96Hz
XWAYLAND11 connected 1920x1080+5760+0 (0x29) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 480mm x 270mm
    Identifier: 0x55c
    Timestamp:  767795
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      5.3:inf:-0.66
    Brightness: 0.63
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       3
    CRTCs:      3
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
  1920x1080 (0x29) 173.000MHz -HSync +VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1920 start 2048 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock  67.16KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1120           clock  59.96Hz
```

Comment: Are you sure the docking station can handle 3 monitors? Also from the Dell support site SLN316828_en_US__2icon Note: The Dell Docking Station WD19/WD19S will not function on a device with any USB-C port. Verify that your laptop supports DisplayPort over USB-C protocol.

Comment: Also from the Dell support site SLN316828_en_US__2icon Note: Linux operating system is unable to physically turn-off built-in display, the external display numbers are one less than the display numbers listed in above tables.
If the Display Port Data Rate is HBR2, then, the maximum resolution that Linux supports is 8192 x 8192 (counted with built-in display plus external display).

Comment: the computer does support dp over usb-c (as evidence by the fact that two monitors does work), I will verify that the dock (and the gpu now that I think about it) can handle three monitors, but I assumed they do since all monitors are detected and I can place windows in the fourth monitor with shift+super even though the monitor shows no signal

Comment: The second comment I made references a Linux issue with the dock. Maybe check out the Dell site.

Comment: As far as I saw, both xps 13 9310 and WD19B support HBR3, and the max number of displays the integrated graphics can handle is 4 (Intel Xe Graphics), so I'm guessing it's either a bandwith issue (maybe three monitors is too much for HBR3) or a driver issue

Comment: My guess it is too much for the HBR3

Comment: Tried setting all monitors to minimum resolution and then all monitors worked so I guess that proves it's a bandwidth limitation. I think if I hook up the third display to the second thunderbolt port it would solve the issue.